# AVPlayer seek vs AVPlayerItem seek

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

Which one is more accurate?

- [AVPlayer seek(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387741-seek)

```
func seek(to time: CMTime, 
          toleranceBefore: CMTime, 
          toleranceAfter: CMTime, 
          completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```

- [AVPlayerItem seek(to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1387753-seek)

```
func seek(to time: CMTime, 
          toleranceBefore: CMTime, 
          toleranceAfter: CMTime, 
          completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

Comment: i think `seek `.

Comment: Yes, AVPlayer seek